# How to pass data between views using stateParameters (not routes) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, state

I have some views in my applications, and I have hard time to show the data when moving from one view to another.

I have a list of news and when I click on the particular news I want the view for that particular news to be shown. Here is my code:

My app.js :

```
 .state('app.list', {
                    url: "/list",
                    views: {
                        'appScreen': {
                            templateUrl: "list.html",
                            controller: 'List.Ctrl'
                        }
                    }
                })

                 .state('app.singleview', {
                     url: "/list/:newsId",
                     views: {
                         'appScreen': {
                             templateUrl: "single.html",
                             controller: 'SingleCtrl'
                         }
                     }
                 })
```

My controllers:

```
ListCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', 'datacontext'];
    function ListCtrl( $http, $scope, datacontext) {

        $scope.list = [];

        datacontext.getPosts().then(function (posts) {
            console.log('posts', posts);
            $scope.list= posts;
        }, function(reason) {
            alert(reason);
        });
```

The following controller is the one which will show me the single news and I have written some code but is not correct. In the URL I get the ID but I can't manage to show the data for that ID.

```
SingleCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'datacontext'];
    function ListNewCtrl($scope, $stateParams, datacontext) {
        $scope.New = getNewsById($stateParams.newsId);
        function getNewsById(id) {
            datacontext.getPosts().then(function(posts) {

                var found = null;
                for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                    if (posts[i].id == id) {
                        found = posts[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return found;
            })
        }

    };
```

So in this controller what I am trying to do is get the ID and match it with postsId, and then show the data accordingly but it does no seem to work

Comment: `getNewsById()` doesn't return anything so `$scope.New` will always be undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused with the asynchronism. The code should be

```
    getNewsById($stateParams.newsId);

    function getNewsById(id) {
        datacontext.getPosts().then(function(posts) {

            var found = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                if (posts[i].id == id) {
                    $scope.New = posts[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So that, when the success callback is executed, the `New` scope variable is initialized by the found post.

That said, I have a hard time understanding why you're getting a whole list of posts from the backend instead of using a REST service returning a single post by ID. If you did, it would be reduced to

```
function getNewsById(id) {
    datacontext.getPost(id).then(function(post) {
        $scope.New = post;
    });
}
```

Comment: It works thank you so much. I just started learning angular so I don't get all the concepts.

Comment: I will have the posts in my server so I need to show them on my app . I put them on the backend for now for simplicity reason while I am developing.
Thank you for the suggestion, I will keep that in mind

Comment: the backend and the server are the same thing. What I'm telling you is that you should not get a list of posts to show only one of them by ID.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean... I want to load the data once and then call them when I need them. 
I have not done a REST service before so .... But I will check it to see how it works.
If you have any suggestions with examples or books , please let me know